# How to force a partnership in offline files online?

Tags: windows, offline-files

I've set up sync partnerships to two servers on LAN. One server comes up nicely and sync works, while the other partnership appears to be permanently off-line.

I've disabled in GP the slow mode (anyway the connection is over LAN). doing net use \myserver\share neatly prompts for login and says it's OK, but the partnership stays off-line.

How to force it? I can't just nuke it as I have changes on the offlined share.